# DB2 insert performance

Tags: java, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to do a bulk insert into DB/2 from an Excel file.
I am running WildFly 12 on my Windows 10 PC. DB/2 is running on a VM under CentOS 7.

Using POI SAX methods, reading the complete XLSX file with 2.5M records takes 80 seconds.

I started off using simple inserts in my EJB program with literals to insert into the table. This took about 1.5 hours.

After reading https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogid=2&blogaid=602 I changed to prepared statements using batches. I also first write to a Global Temporary Table and at the end use "INSERT INTO  SELECT ... FROM ".

Turned off auto commit.

The end result is still taking up an hour, or 750 inserts / second.

Prepare the items:

```
        // get connection using DriverManager class
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:db2://192.168.0.5:50000/mydb",
                    "hussain", 
                    "hussain");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            out.println("Failed to get connection");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Clear the table
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE " + strMainTable + " IMMEDIATE");
            statement.execute("ALTER TABLE " + strMainTable + " ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 1 ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY");
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            out.println("Failed to clear table<br>");
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("DROP TABLE " + strTempTable);
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            out.println("Failed to delete table<br>");
        }
        // In DB2:
        // CREATE USER TEMPORARY TABLESPACE USERTEMP MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
        // GRANT USE OF TABLESPACE USERTEMP TO USER HUSSAIN
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE " + strTempTable + " (" + 
                    " COL1 VARCHAR(900 OCTETS), " + 
                    " COL2 VARCHAR(20 OCTETS), " + 
                    " COL3 VARCHAR(225 OCTETS), " + 
                    " COL4 VARCHAR(500 OCTETS)" + 
                    " ) NOT LOGGED ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ");

            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            out.println("Failed to create table<br>");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Step 2.B: Creating JDBC Statement 
        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + strTempTable + " (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            statementInsert = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            out.println("Failed to prepare statement<br>");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

Then, in the loop, I read the XLSX file and

```
            try {
                if(batchRows > 10000) {
                    batchRows = 0;
                    statementInsert.executeBatch();
                }
                //statementInsert.execute();
                batchRows++;
                //lBigBatchRows++;
                statementInsert.addBatch();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

At the end:

```
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("INSERT INTO " + strMainTable + 
                    " (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) " +
                    " SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM " + strTempTable);
            statement.execute("DROP TABLE " + strTempTable);
            connection.commit();
```

Yes, DB/2 is running in a VM so write speeds are effected by lots of factors. Still, 750 records / second is extremely slow. The author of the article says his worst speed was 3000/s and best was 140k/s. Would be nice to get close.

What else should I be looking at?

Comment: Look into `PreparedStatement` and its batching methods.

Comment: @Kayaman As I gave in the code above, I am using addBatch() method instead of executing the prepared statement for each insert.

Comment: Ah! I am rerunning it with minor changes right now. The inserts into the temp table which is a Global Temp Table have finished in 102 seconds. That means that the remaining 57 minutes are being taken up by the "INSERT INTO... SELECT FROM..." statement. Hmm...

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that, well at least you have a good baseline. Why are you inserting to another table at first? It can't be any faster, if the alternative is to insert into a truncated table. You might want to try tuning your batch size, try with something like `200-1000` batch size and see how it affects the time.

Comment: I thought that it was the insert which was time consuming, so made a temp table without any indexes and no logging so that that step would run faster. But now that I see that the main time hog is writing to the main table, let me see...

Comment: @HussainAkbar Row-By-Row inserts will be slower than multi-row inserts. Separately, why are you using a slow `insert into ...select from` to populate the final table? Consider load-from-cursor. Separately, if your target Db2-server configuration is badly or default configured this can have a big impact on elapsed times.

Comment: @mao Yes, row by row is slower, hence the addBatch that I am using. Yes, the DB2 is default configured; haven't changed anything. Loading from cursor is preferred over insert from? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @HussainAkbar refer to the Db2-Knowledge-Centre for your version of Db2-LUW. Study how to use both the ADMIN_CMD stored procedure, and how to use load-from-cursor with that stored procedure. Separately, configuring the Db2-LUW to optimize insert is not programming but a competent DBA will know all the tricks.

Comment: @mao Tried out the ADMIN_CMD. The result was almost unbelievable; the table copied within 45 seconds. Grand total import time is now 220 seconds. Thanks a lot. Please post this as answer so that I can mark it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment-thread mentions populating an unlogged session table (declared global temporary table) in an acceptable time, but you found that the bulk of the elapsed time was spent doing a logged insert-into-select-from the session table to the final table.

Logged inserts are significantly slower than load, but sometimes are the only option.

You can also speed up logged inserts on Db2-LUW using various techniques that are outside the scope of this question but which are well known to DBAs.

My suggestion was to use the [ADMIN_CMD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0005437.html) stored procedure to invoke a load-from-cursor action to populate the final table.

You tested this approach and found the performance to be acceptable.

Notice that in an HA configuration you will need to consider the impact of the load, possibly needing to use `load copy` or other approaches for synchronising or recovery (database restore etc).

The approach might also need to be reconsidered if Db2 is running on a cloud service, depending on what the vendor offers.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of logging of the inserts to the main table.

alter table main_table activate not logged initially.

That setting will remain until you do a commit.

If you can export the excel as comma delimited file you can use load command which is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Alter Your *strmaintable* Id column cache 1000, no order.

Id integer not null generated by default as identity (start with 1, increment by 1, cache 1000, no order)

https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/databases/articles/dm-0403wilkins/#table5